# Qt/Android/CMake: Custom AndroidManifest.xml not taken into account

Tags: android, qt, cmake

I am building a Qt project with Qt for Android.

I need to add a `uses-feature` tag in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file. For this, I made a template with Qt Creator then added **android/AndroidManifest.xml** file to the app sources.

Whatever I put in the **android/AndroidManifest.xml** file, it is ignored and a default/internal file is used.

Here is my **CMakeLists.txt** file :

```
    set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
    
    find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
    find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
    
    file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp
      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.ui
      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h
      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.qrc
      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/android/AndroidManifest.xml
    )
    if(ANDROID)
      set(ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION 21)
      set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/android/)
    
      add_library(myapp SHARED ${SOURCES})
    else()
      add_executable(evotest ${SOURCES})
    endif()
    
    target_link_libraries(myapp Qt5::Widgets)
    
    install(TARGETS myapp DESTINATION bin)
```

Answer (score 8):

The solution was to set **ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR** this way :

```
set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/android CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

Now, the file `android/AndroidManifest.xml` is taken into account to build the android package.

Comment: where did your find it?your refrence .how about other options

Comment: Does not work for Qt6.

Answer (score 3):

In Qt6 its a property and has a QT_ prefix.
So custom AndroidManifest can be set in these ways:

```
set_target_properties(myapp PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
    ...
    ...
    QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android
)
```

---

```
set_property(TARGET myapp APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-target-property-qt-android-package-source-dir.html

Comment: Correct answer for Qt6. Thanks.