# How to make Qt Creator 10.0.2 use an edited AndroidManifest.xml file?

Tags: android, android-manifest, qt-creator

I am trying to write a Qt Widgets application in Qt Creator 10.0.2 for Android under Ubuntu 22.04. I use the CMake build system, the "Android Qt 6.5.1 Clang armeabi-v7a" kit, with build-tools version 31.0.0 and build platform SDK android-34.

I want to make the app always landscape, so I need to change the `screenOrientation` option in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to `landscape`. So I changed the manifest file `(project folder)/build-(project name)-Android_Qt_6_5_1_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/android-build/AndroidManifest.xml`. But when I run the application, the screen is still portrait. I saw that the manifest file got overwritten and the orientation setting becomes `unspecified` again.

I've seen the answers given in [Landscape mode in Qt-Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546117/landscape-mode-in-qt-android-application). Apparently the solutions there are obsolete. The current Qt Creator doesn't make a `.pro` file, and Projects > Run doesn't appear to have an option for creating the manifest file.

As for the answer by Zappy Mans (actually from https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deploying-android.html), I've followed it (clicked the Create Templates button and provided a path) but the error `Could not update the project file (project path)/(project name)` appeared. It actually creates a manifest file in the path I provided, but it's not used. It appears that `(project folder)/build-(project name)-Android_Qt_6_5_1_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/android-build/AndroidManifest.xml` is still used, and it's overwritten every time I click Run.

Any idea how to make a permanent change to the manifest file which is actually used? I'm stuck here.

As for the minimum reproducible example, just create a new Qt Widgets application project, put a button somewhere to check the orientation, and click Run. Then attempt the modifications that I made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt/Android/CMake: Custom AndroidManifest.xml not taken into account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831676/qt-android-cmake-custom-androidmanifest-xml-not-taken-into-account)